# How do more features lower the bias?

Tags: bias

The question is fairly straight forward.

I always assumed that a model will not perform well if there are not enough features because all the variables which cause variation in the data are not accounted for.

However, I'm not sure if my hypothesis is correct.

What is the reason that creating more features will lower the bias?

Answer (score 0):

Bias characterize how well your model describes real process. But not all of the features are matter. For example if you want to estimate salary of a person feature "Highest degree of education" would matter a lot and feature "Like blue socks" wouldn't matter (at least much). So, more features COULD reduce bias.

Actually, it's a whole area of statistics to build a model with needed features. One would examine p-value of a hypothesis if feature does matter in the model. I do recommend you to check out [ISLR book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). It's free, has a lot of good ideas and straightforward explanations.